# Why doesn't my list refresh in my listbox when I change an item?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with list and listview.

I started a project and added a listview. After this I created a class which has two elements e.g. key1 and key2 both are strings.

I bind the text of the itemTemplate of the listbox to this keys and everything is fine.
then I set `listbox1.ItemsSource = data;`
and data is: `List<OwnListData> data = new List<OwnListData>();`
everything is displayd.

but the problem is, when I change an item of data, the list does now show any changes. How do I get the listview to refresh`?

EDIT: a quick and dirty solution is to make

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = null;
listbox1.ItemsSource = data;
```

after each change, but this is not the nice way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection<OwnListData>` instead of `List<OwnListData>`. I've faced this problem too.
It seems that Lists and Enumerables can't be used with ListBox because they don't update the UI.

Hope it helps